# Application to automatically switch windows unless there is user activity

Tags: windows, autoit

I'm looking for an application (or script such as for [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)) that will automatically switch between multiple windows unless user activity (mouse movement, key presses) is detected. I'm creating a wallboard that needs to operate in two modes:

1. *Interactive mode* - user is at the station and interacting with the window. No window switching.
2. *Screensaver mode* - after a specified amount of time with no user activity, the script/program engages and cycles between multiple browser windows.

I found this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/327676/application-to-automatically-switch-between-two-applications-in-windows) which recommended AutoIt, but I don't see a way to detect user activity with AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **_Timer_GetIdleTime()** function in AutoIT.

[AutoIt: _Timer_GetIdleTime()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Timer_GetIdleTime.htm)