# Open and Select a file in an existing Explorer window

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

I'd like to open and select a file in an *existing* Explorer window from the command line.

- Opens a new window:

  ```
  explorer.exe /select, "FILE_PATH"
  ```
- Runs the file:

  ```
  cmd.exe /c start "" "FILE_PATH"
  ```

Is it possible to use this, and have it select a specific file?

```
cmd.exe /c start "" "FOLDER_PATH"
```

Comment: I'm using [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) and I'd like to open a file's containing folder in a new tab in the existing window. 

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is not only relevant to QTTabBar. In general: can you open a folder in an existing window and select a file?
Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed. I want to accomplish the following: **1)** Open up a specific folder. **2)** Open up a specific file within that same folder. **3)** DO NOT open a new Explorer window but rather navigate in the existing one (or open a new tab if you use QTTabBar). *** I'd like to use the command in Notepad++: Open the containing folder of the active file and also select it. So it's not limited to a certain file extension. *** Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Great. I appreciate that.

Comment: Yaron - Check out and test with the batch script here: http://textuploader.com/dkl5q to start with and confirm if that works as expected for the first parts of your request and let me know. If I'm on the right track I will move forward with more testing as soon as I get a chance with the QTTabBar software. This will help me determine if you need adjustments, if something is way off from your expectations, etc. Obviously you'll need to change the value of the file and the folder variables to match those you will test with.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your kindness.*** I've slightly modified your script and it works perfectly. https://s9.postimg.org/a2d9opy3z/Bat_Script.png *** I couldn't figure out yet how to pass the FolderPath and FileName as arguments.

Comment: I've figured out how to use the arguments: https://s14.postimg.org/s4mq9txj5/Script.png. *** There's one problem: if the file name includes certain characters (e.g. {07E520A6-15F9-4D0F-A577-74945ABDC1DE}.reg) or the characters are not Latin (but Hebrew in my case) it won't get selected.*** Thank you so much. I'm really grateful. *** Any up-voting/appreciation mechanism on this site?

Comment: With your permission, another question: the BAT file is "used" for a while after executing it; that is: it's "Read Only". Any idea why? *** BTW, I'm using NirCmd in order to hide the console. `nircmd.exe exec hide "Bat File" "Folder Path" "File Name"`. *** Many thanks again.

Comment: For the Hebrew deal check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478940/how-to-fix-a-batch-file-with-an-hebrew-font and how to use chcp to help with that. I could not get this recreated for the file with the name of  `{07E520A6-15F9-4D0F-A577-74945ABDC1DE}.txt` when I tested with it, it seems to open fine on my system but may be related to your locale and the chcp tips from there may help resolve. There's likely another process that's making the batch file read only like setting an `attrib +r` with another process.

Comment: I've encoded the BAT file to Windows 1255 (Hebrew). The problem is with the VBS file which is encoded to UTF 16-LE. How can I change that encoding from the BAT file? Alternatively, I could create and keep a VBS file with the correct encoding; but then the `ECHO Set p = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> "%TempVBSFile%"` part would have to overwrite the previous entries. *** As I'm using QTTabBar, I need to use `start "" %1` instead of `explorer` (which opens a new window); for some reason on every third-or-so use of the batch script (from Notepad++), the Explorer window remains in the background

Comment: ... But that is a minor issue. *** Allow me to thank you again for your kind help. Highly appreciated. *** I've up-voted some of your answers. I'll certainly remember to up-vote your answer in this thread. :) *** Have a nice weekend and enjoy your time with the family.

Comment: `SendKeys()` does not support Unicode.

See https://superuser.com/questions/1230810/vbs-select-one-file-in-a-folder for an alternative.

@McDonald's,
Thanks again.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1233283/vbs-select-item-in-windows-explorer-last-active-window

Comment: @Yaron vbscript is old and so is the sendkeys accessible from it, but the sendkeys in .net e.g. in C# or VB, does support unicode. so e.g. VB's  SendKeys.Send does.

Comment: You have a command to open a folder and select a file, and you have a command to run a file, why don't you just use both commands?

Comment: Thanks for your help. *** I might try the other script languages. *** I don't want to run the file. Just select it.

Comment: Here is an example of vbscript with sendkeys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198574/does-or-can-vbscripts-sendkeys-support-unicode    Note, if you used C#, note that C# is a proper programming language, not a scripting language

Comment: Thank you very much. *** I later realized that sending keys is not enough as I need to activate first a specific Windows-Explorer window. *** Sorry for the confusion by the questions I posted in different stages.

Answer (score 2):

CMD is an interpreter; gives users an interface/language to access features of Windows™. It does NOT give direct access to system memory or CPU registers (a feature of lower level programming language). 
To *"open and select a file"* (in explorer window) you would:

```
explorer.exe /select, "FILE_PATH"
```

To just open a explorer window  to select a file manually, you would:

```
cmd.exe /c start "" "FOLDER_PATH"
```

If *"an existing Explorer window"* is already open, and you want to just select a file manually, you would *Activate* the explorer window (that is already open instead of opening another explorer window).

Windows manipulation is a feature of GUI and CMD provides a CLI to Windows™, hence you'd need to write code in a (lower level) language or one that gives you access to such features ie. to activate open windows eg. other interpreters (AutoHotKey/AutoIt/VBS), compilers (C/VBA), or assembly/machine code (which can be interfaced via CMD (`forfiles` or `fc`) or related utilities eg. `Debug` or `Certutil`)

See:
[CMD command in Windows to switch to an already open application](https://superuser.com/questions/971563/cmd-command-in-windows-to-switch-to-an-already-open-application)

A workaround would be to open your chosen folder via `explorer "FOLDER_PATH"` for manual selection of file or autoselected via `explorer.exe /select, "FILE_PATH"` & close the existing explorer window via `taskkill /im explorer.exe /fi "windowtitle eq %title%"`

Comment: Thank you Zimba. I haven't dealt with this issue for a long time. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Someone reading this in future might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered exactly the same problem. Now I use Listary to solve this problem, with a preset action shown in the following figure:
[Listary action setting for opening the containing folder that can be captured by QTTabBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfNrf.png)

The listary action is set as:

```
path: explorer.exe
parameter: /select, "{action_path}"
```

I don't know what Listary have done with the script, but it just works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241746)