# VBS: Select one file in a folder

Tags: windows-explorer, vbscript

The following code selects arg1 in a Windows Explorer folder:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """")
WScript.Sleep 400

' objShell.SendKeys("^a{F5}")       ' Deslect All.

Set objShellAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
On Error Resume Next        ' For new unsaved files.
With objShellAPP.Windows(objShellAPP.Windows.Count - 1).document
.SelectItem .Folder.Items.Item(WScript.Arguments(1)), 17
End With

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objShellAPP = Nothing
```

If fileA is already selected in the folder and fileB is passed as arg1, both files are selected.

How can I have fileA deselected and only fileB selected?
The commented line `objShell.SendKeys("^a{F5}")`is a workaround, but there must be a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the following vbs code can help **objWsShell.Run("explorer.exe /select," & itmToSelect)**: it runs an instance of explorer.exe to browse local folders. To the instance is passed the switch /select and a parameter itmToSelect that is the path (as string) to a file or folder to select. After the execution of the code you will have the itmToSelect (file or folder) highlighted into the file/folder browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the value of 17 for the parameter *dwFlags*. This value is an integer representing the combination of flags you want set.

You derive this value by a bitwise `OR` operation using the flag values. I think 17 is probably `16 OR 1` (give the item focus; select item) There is a flag value of 4 to "deselect all but the specified item." `17 OR 4` = 21.

Use `OR` to combine flags; use `AND` to test against a particular flag to see if it is set (21 AND 4 = 4); use `AND not` to toggle one flag off (21 AND not(4) = 17)

[SelectItem Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774047(v=vs.85).aspx)

[random link: Stackoverflow - How do integer flags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440473/how-do-integer-flags-work)

Comment: Note: flags make more sense if you consider them in binary and then consider that binary is analogous with a bank of toggle switches. So "8" is 1000 or On-Off-Off-Off.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. `21` works like a charm.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1233283/vbs-select-item-in-windows-explorer-last-active-window