# VBS: Select item in Windows Explorer last active window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, vbscript, selection

I use the following code to select a file in a Windows Explorer window:

```
Set objShellAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShellAPP.Open(WScript.Arguments(0))
WScript.Sleep(300)

On Error Resume Next        ' For new unsaved files.
With objShellAPP.Windows(objShellAPP.Windows.Count - 1).document
.SelectItem .Folder.Items.Item(WScript.Arguments(1)), 29
End With

Set objShellAPP = Nothing
```

`objShellAPP.Open()` opens the folder in the last active window;

`objShellAPP.Windows.Count - 1` is not necessarily that window.

How can I get the last active window for the `With objShellAPP.Windows(---).document` line?

Thank you.

---

See:

[Open and Select a file in an existing Explorer window](https://superuser.com/questions/1226136/open-and-select-a-file-in-an-existing-explorer-window)

[VBS: Select one file in a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1230810/vbs-select-one-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code the first Windows Explorer window is activated and then a folder is opened there (I use [QTTabbar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/)).

```
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim winFolder
For Each wFolder In objShellApp.Windows
On Error Resume Next
isFolder = wFolder.document.folder  ' An IE window does not support ".document.folder". We get the first Windows Explorer window.
If Err = 0 Then
wFolder.Visible = True
Set winFolder = wFolder
Exit For
End If
Next

objShellApp.Open(WScript.Arguments(0))
WScript.Sleep(300)

If NOT WScript.Arguments(1) = "" Then
If winFolder = Empty Then
Set winFolder = objShellApp.Windows(objShellApp.Windows.Count - 1)      ' A Windows Explorer window opened with objShellApp.Open(WScript.Arguments(0)) is the last one in the index (Count - 1).
End If

On Error Resume Next        ' For new unsaved files.
With winFolder.document
.SelectItem .Folder.Items.Item(WScript.Arguments(1)), 29
End With
End If

Set winFolder = Nothing
Set objShellApp = Nothing
```

As for a better way to distinguish between Windows-Explorer and Internet-Explorer:

[VBS: Distinguis between Windows-Explorer and Internet-Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1233712/vbs-distinguis-between-windows-explorer-and-internet-explorer)